# ASP Server Error -Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Tags: vb6, asp-classic

I am looking into a very old ASP code after so many years. I am able to make it run on VS2008. However, when I click on the page I am frequently getting

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed 

/xxy/Search/includes/criteria_toolnewbag.asp, line 19 

Invalid class string
```

I know the COM components are on VB6 and is this an error because of COM registration? If yes or No how can this be solved?

Comment: First show us what is on line 19 in /xxy/Search/includes/criteria_toolnewbag.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code failed because ASP was not able to *Create* the specified object. Most likely you're trying to create a COM object that is not registered/available on the server. Let us know what object you were trying to create in `criteria_toolnewbag.asp, line 19` so that you can get help.

Normally, if it is possible to re-install the component (i.e. you have access to the setup/installer) then give it a try. Otherwise you might have to locate the DLL for the component and do (at your own risk):

```
regsvr32 foo.dll /u
regsvr32 foo.dll
```

Comment: It was DLL registration..I re-registered it and it started working for me.